# How do I remove all elements except one in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, class, removeall, remove-if

I'm using jQuery 1.12.  After clicking on a TD, I want to remove all elements within it except the one with class "savedBlock", so I tried

```
$(elt).closest('td').find('.savedBlock').show()
$(elt).closest('td').not('.savedBlock').remove()
```

Unfortunately this is having the effect of removing everything . At least everything disappears from the table cell after I run this.  If I comment out the `$(elt).closest('td').not('.savedBlock').remove()` line, nothing is removed but now I see more than what I want.  Any suggestions?

Comment: So the savedBlock is being applied to the td?

Comment: Can you show your HTML? It's hard to know host all the elements are related. `.not()` applies to the element itself, `.find()` looks for descendants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$('td').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).children().not(".savedBlock").remove();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(elt).closest('td:not(.savedBlock)').remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(elt).closest('td:not(.savedBlock)').remove()
```

is how it should be done. the colon is before the not